# Investing in basket of stocks in the style of ETF but without re-balancing

Tags: investing, etf

Is there any product that offers you to at once buy baskets of stocks according to the market at that moment (or some time in the past) like ETF's do but without any re-balancing after?

I think a large part of the cost (TER and/or swap fees) of ETF's is due to the re-balancing. There seems to be a strange obsession with exactly keeping up with the market when there is no real reason to mind small deviations. They might do better or worse but it probably doesn't hugely increase the spread and it should not affect the expectation value at all. The main appeal of ETF's is that it is the easiest way to invest in many stocks at once in order to diversify. But you can do the same by buying one basket once and holding it forever. I also wouldn't mind buying an outdated say "2005" basket if that was when this "stable ETF" happened to start. (And if there would be multiple such funds with different start dates picking different ones each time you invest would help diversify further.)

Does such a product exist or do I really need to buy individual stocks to avoid any fees/losses related to re-balancing?

---

I am based in the EU and would be most interested in products available to EU residents.

Comment: "I think a large part of the cost (TER and/or swap fees) of ETF's is due to the re-balancing" Why do you think that? There is actually very little rebalancing needed for market-cap-weighted index trackers, except.

Comment: I would bet (but cannot prove) that the transaction fees (explicit and implicit) would be more than the relatively low fees you pay for passive ETFs.

Comment: @DStanley, One time fees (which is what I think you mean with transaction fees) hardly matter over the long time. It is fees that compound that matter. Take for example the relatively low TER of 0.2% p.a. That can easily cost you say 100000* ((1.075)^30 - (1.075-0.002)^30) = 47569. (Here I assumed an average yield of 7.5% and a starting capital of 100000, doesn't actually matter what currency for the math.)

Comment: I thought that because it is the only thing the ETF actually has to do after the initial purchase. It is the only ongoing service to the consumer. It is true that you are possibly paying for things like marketing though, so I am not sure.

Comment: I was thinking of the transaction fees of buying every stock in an index.

Comment: @DStanley, right but it would be weird to charge that as a p.a. since you only need to do it once (you need to do it more if you rebalance, but absent that it shouldn't be an annual fee).

Comment: You are paying for the people to administer the fund, transaction fees for what little rebalancing is necessary (usually quarterly), marketing, etc.

Comment: Right so I'm looking for any product that avoids that. An effective 50000$ price tag (over 30 years) on a 100000$ investment seems rather steep if what I effectively want is to just one time be able to buy a basket of stocks rather than individual ones and no service afterwards whatsoever.

Comment: You do realize that in your 30 year example, you would miss out on most of the big gainers in the major indices because they did not exist when you bought it? (Tesla, Amazon, netflix, monster, ...). You would wish to have paid these very low fees and not been stuck with Xerox type stocks. Also, rebalancing is not the main expense; the firms need to keep track of the portfolio, buyers and sellers, there is lots of regulatory requirements,...

Comment: @AKdemy, so if you are so sure that newcomers outperform things already in place do you weight them stronger? Most people don't. I don't think newcomers systematically outperform things already in the index (in fact I have read about a small bias in the opposite direction).You are probably right about there being hidden costs since no one is doing it but it isn't that clear why I couldn't set up a profitable business offering the cheapest service where I buy once (taking a fee), do nothing for years and thus not charging a fee) and then sell once when realizing (again charging a one time fee).

Comment: There is an interesting paper by [Hendrik Bessembinder, Francis J. and Mary B. Labriola from ASU’s W. P. Carey School of Business](https://wpcarey.asu.edu/department-finance/faculty-research/do-stocks-outperform-treasury-bills) which shows that  the largest returns come from very few stocks overall — just 86 stocks have accounted for $16 trillion in shareholder wealth creation (SWC). Out of these, Apple, Microsoft, Amazon, Alphabet and Facebook collectively explained 22.1% of the increase in stock market SWC from the end of 2016 to the end of 2019.

Comment: I never mentioned hidden cost. I just wanted to point out that a large part of the fees is required to keep the firm running (and not because of rebalancing).

Comment: Well with "hidden fees" I meant the costs to "keep a firm running" you mention. Note that these are apparent costs for "not doing something" and therefore it is not that clear what they are for. I guess you need to have some employee "running things" to remember what the hell the company is doing even when there is nothing to do except buying when people buy in and selling once they cash out. But I would think that on a large scale these costs should be nearly nothing.

Comment: Note also that one of the top 5 performers in that paper was already on the S&P in 1957 when it was created (or at least first took the form it still is today) namely Exxon Mobil Corp. So I think you would have been fine just holding those original companies all this time. It would be really fun if someone could actually do the comparison of the original S&P vs the changing version. (You might have to think of the proper definitions for stocks that went private/bankrupt/liquidated.)

(It is probably not a good example to learn from though. Markets got a lot more efficient since 1957.)

Comment: I think you just answered it yourself. Over the past 50 years, 86 original constituents of the S&P 500 have survived through time. no need to think of a proper definition of stocks that went bankrupt or were liquidated. They all simply lost all their value....

Comment: In US we have [Unit Investment Trusts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_investment_trust) which issue a fixed set of ownership interests of a fixed or nearly-fixed portfolio; I don't know if there's anything similar in EU. This avoids both rebalancing (which costs very little) and ongoing issue/redemption (which is more, but nowhere near all). They still need to maintain shareholder records and distribute both communications and net dividends and gains ('accumulating' investment trusts in US are taxed more so people don't buy them) as well as compliance activities and costs.

Comment: @AKdemy, I think it requires some thinking. Stocks went off market but didn't lose value (think twitter recently). They either had to be liquidated or their value is now unknown. So let's say they were liquidated. That means they need to be reinvested at that time in the rest of the shares. I don't have time to check your claim but did all but 86 go bankrupt? Or did they get acquired by other companies? For those that that went bankrupt did they pay out anything to the share holders (after resolving debt that had precedence?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, that sounds interesting! It seems to be the closest thing to an answer to my question until now.

Answer (score 2):

An index fund follows the recipe defined by the company that establishes the index. Many index funds then follow that recipe. Therefore the biggest expenses related to an active fund: research, transaction fees to buy and sell based on the research, and taxes; are avoided with a passive index fund. For indexes like the S&P 500 the number of changes during a typical year are small.

There are costs related to having an account that all funds and fund companies have to have such as website costs, telephone support, computers, utilities, and staff. You would also like those funds to follow all the accounting and government regulations. You also want them to provide quarterly and annual statements.

To keep the expenses low pick an index fund.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the holdings in an index fund, and replicate it on your own. That of course would incur a lot of transaction fees, so in practice it's not feasible for most investors.

Other than that, you would miss any new companies that get added to the index. And when you get dividends, to avoid deviating too much from the market, you should be reinvesting them in all of your holdings, not just in the company issuing the dividend. More transaction fees there.

Funds have their own transaction fees (generally not included in their expense ratio), but they're much smaller because of economies of scale, and they're partially offset by security lending income. When you look at high-quality index funds, you'll see that they have minimal tracking error, the difference between real and index returns.

Saving on transaction fees, monitoring companies coming in and out of the index, making it easy to reinvest dividends, and saving you time/hassle, all for ~0.05% is a fantastic deal.

Comment: It might be the best deal available. I wouldn't say fantastic. The 0.05% sounds small but can add up to a lot of money over many years. Direct indexing seems competitive (one time transactions fees matter a lot less than recurring fees). It is just a bit of a hassle. (Security lending is of course also possible when owning the stocks directly.)
Missing out on some companies means being slightly less diversified (larger variance) but shouldn't affect your expected return.
It is a shame no company offers to automate direct indexing without recurring fees (only one time transaction fees).

Comment: The public markets worldwide have about 9000 listed companies. Let's say you want to only buy the top 3000, which already misses out on a lot of small-cap diversification. At $5 per trade, that would be $15,000. If you held that over 40 years without further trades, you would need a *starting* portfolio of $750,000 for that to match a 0.05% expense ratio. That doesn't account for the fact that by putting costs up front, you miss out on compounding on those fees (on average, for 20 years), so it's likely a much larger figure.

Comment: In that scenario, you also don't get newly listed companies, which over 40 years can completely change the market. You don't get to properly reinvest dividends without paying $15k again. And you have no way to add any money to your portfolio without again paying $15k. And that still doesn't account for selling your shares. You have to squint very hard to think that index funds are not a great deal for individual investors.

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting a bit:

Low cost traditional index funds have no transaction costs, which makes rebalancing free (except for capital gains tax).

The biggest advantage ETFs have, really, is that traditional funds may be less tax-efficient since you pay tax on their dividends each year.

It's probably a good idea to run some numbers on both options and see how that difference affects you. I've seen no reason to move to ETFs.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your answer. Are you saying there exist index funds with little to no fees? ETFs generally have 0.05%-0.25% Total Expense Ratio's (TER) depending on what index it is following. Do you know something with lesser fees? (These fees are of course already reasonably low but can still easily accumulate to say over 50000$ over say 30 years. If I can avoid these fees at only a small cost to my diversification that would be very interesting.)

Comment: Or are you saying the fees that are there are for something else than rebalancing? (It is the only thing the ETF does really.)

Comment: @Kvothe: There are quite a number of well-diversified options where the expense ratio is in the 0.02-0.04%/year range.

Comment: @BenVoigt, are these also available in Europe? At Interactive Brokers (Ireland) for example I haven't found any stock ETF below 0.05%. I have heard there are some US ones that are not available in Europe due to some regulations. Perhaps these are those?

Comment: @keshlam, can you give an example? What is a  traditional index fund, an actively managed one? What is its TER? Can they be bought in Europe?

Comment: @Kvothe: I have no idea whether any are available in European brokerage account.  If that's important to you, you might want to add it to the question (where you ask "Does such a product exist?")

Comment: @BenVoigt, thansk, yes definitely useful information either way.

Comment: Index funds are, by definition, not actively managed except to follow the index. "Traditional" mutual fund shares are bought and sold directly with the investment house running the fund, rather than through the stock exchange, and therefore do not have the costs of running the transaction through the exchange. I'm using funds operated by Columbia Thread needle, but there are many equivalents on the market  with slightly different details, just as there are for ETFs.

Comment: @keshlam, thanks. Your example seems to have a Net Expense Ratio
0.20% which if I can naively compare it with the TER is also on the high side compared to ETFs. So they seem to have the same problem.

Comment: Thermodynamics: You can't win, you can't break even, you can't quit the game. Operating costs have to come from somewhere.